# How should I prove a set is convex?

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis

> Given a set $$ \mathbf{S} = \{ \mathbf{x}\:|\: \mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{V}\mathbf{x}=1 \} $$ where $\mathbf{V}$ is a positive semidefinite matrix. How to prove this set is convex?

I tried in the following way:

First, let $\mathbf{x_1}$ and $\mathbf{x_2}$ are two elements of $\mathbf{S}$.
I get $\mathbf{x_1}^T\mathbf{V}\mathbf{x_1} = 1$ and $\mathbf{x_2}^T\mathbf{V}\mathbf{x_2} = 1$.

Second, try a derivation of $\mathbf{x_3}^T\mathbf{V}\mathbf{x_3} = 1$,
where $\mathbf{x_3}$ is $t\mathbf{x_1}+(1-t)\mathbf{x_2}$.

What I got is :

$$t^2+(1-t)^2+t(1-t)(\mathbf{x_2}^T\mathbf{V}\mathbf{x_1} + \mathbf{x_1})^T\mathbf{V}\mathbf{x_2}$$

where I don't how to prove this derivation equals to 1.

Comment: Are you sure that there is equality in the definition of $S$?

Comment: Consider the special case when your $x$ comes from $\mathbb{R}^2$, $V$ is the identity, and $S$ is a circle.

Comment: Your set is NOT convex!

Comment: Note that the set $S$ is symmetric about the origin, i.e. $x \in S$ iff $-x \in S$.  Yet $0 \notin S$.  Presumably inequality was meant in the definition of $S$.

Comment: Since $S$ is contained in a real vector space, we have to show that    for all $t \in [0,1]$, $(1-t)x+ty=1$. The condition $x^Tx=1$ implies that matrix is unitary, and so letting $x_1=x$ and $x_2=y$ in the equation above, you can check that it is convex.

Comment: @Mercy, it will be pleasure if any hint could be given.

Comment: @JaivirBaweja, I don't understand how could this $x^Tx = 1$ condition be obtained from $\mathbf{S}$?

Comment: @JuliánAguirre, I'm sure there is equality in the definition of $\mathbf{S}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let
$$
B:\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R},\ B(x,y)=x^TVy,\ 
Q:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R},\ Q(x)=B(x,x).
$$
Let us also define
$$
\nu: X:=\mathbb{R}^n\setminus Q^{-1}(0) \to \mathbb{R}^n,\ \nu(x)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{Q(x)}}. 
$$
Then $S=Q^{-1}(1)$, and for every $x \in X$ we have
$$
Q(\nu(x))=(\nu(x))^TV\nu(x)=\frac{x^TVx}{Q(x)}=\frac{Q(x)}{Q(x)}=1,
$$
i.e. $\nu(X) \subset S$.

For every $x,y \in X$ with $B(x,y)\ne \sqrt{Q(x)Q(y)}$ (e.g. for $B(x,y) \le 0$), and every $t \in [0,1]$ we have
\begin{eqnarray}
Q((1-t)\nu(x)+t\nu(y))&=&(1-t)^2Q(\nu(x))+2t(1-t)B(\nu(x),\nu(y))+t^2Q(\nu(y))\\
&=&t^2+(1-t)^2+2t(1-t)\frac{B(x,y)}{\sqrt{Q(x)Q(y)}}.
\end{eqnarray}
Therefore
$$
Q((1-t)\nu(x)+t\nu(y))=1 \iff \frac{B(x,y)}{\sqrt{Q(x)Q(y)}}=1 \iff B(x,y)=\sqrt{Q(x)Q(y)}.
$$
Hence $S$ is not convex

Comment: That's an incredibly complicated way to go about showing it's not convex. Why don't you just note that $x \in S$ and $-x \in S$, but $\frac{1}{2}(x + (-x)) = 0$ is not? :)

Comment: Is what I did false or just complicated?

Comment: Well, in a sense, both: You haven't shown that the set $\{(x,y) \in X \times X : B(x,y)^2 \neq Q(x) Q(y) \}$ is nonempty. ;-)

Comment: you should read again :D

Comment: You added your edit in the meantime, actually. (I was dragged away from the computer midstream.) Cheers.

Comment: @Mercy, thank you very much.

Comment: @Mercy: You can be sure that if Yanpeng turns in your solution, it will be easy to track for plagiarism. (+1)

Comment: @cardinal, thank you too.

Answer (score 3):

Many authors allow [the empty set to be convex](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis610/convex1-09.pdf) as vacuously satisfying the definition.  The only case in which set $S$ might be said to be convex is this, where "positive semi-definite matrix" $V$ is zero.

Otherwise the set $S$ is nonempty, and any $x \in S$ must necessarily be nonzero.  But as previous commenters point out, then $-x \in S$ and convexity requires $0 \in S$.  Contradiction.

Comment: thanks for your answer @hardmath